# Inequivalent immersions from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry

I've been working through Boothby's book, "An introduction to differentiable manifolds and Riemannian geometry" and am a little stuck in Chapter III, Sec. 4 on the following problem:

Give an example of two inequivalent one-to-one immersions of $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ (i.e. they have the same image $N \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ under the immersion map, but are not related by a diffeomorphism)

Now, I have the following example in mind. Let $G:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be given by $G(t) = (2\cos(g(t) - \pi/2), \sin(2g(t) - \pi))$ where $g(t) = \pi + 2\tan^{-1}(t)$. The resulting manifold $N \equiv G(\mathbb{R})$ is a figure-of-eight that is traversed only once (the figure-of-eight has its node at the origin, which is the image of $t= 0$ and $t \to \pm \infty$). Now let $H:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be given by $H(x^1,x^2) = (x^1,-x^2)$ i.e. a reflection about $x^1$. They both have the same image $N$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. One can check that both $G(t)$ and $H(t)$ are immersions by evaluating the rank of the Jacobian over the domain $t\in (-\infty,\infty)$.

How does one prove that $H : N \to N$ is not a diffeomorphism (the topology being  given by the map $G$) ?

Answer (score 1):

First, be careful with what your maps do (draw  spaces and arrows to keep track of what goes where). You defined $H$ as a map of $\mathbb R^2$ but then talk of it as an immersion of $\mathbb R$.

I don't have the book nearby, but I think that two immersions $G_1$, $G_2$ are *related by diffeomorphism* if there is a diffeomorphism  $\psi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R $ such that $G_2=G_1\circ \psi$. Divide the plane into quadrants, and observe which two quadrants contain $G_1(t)$ when $t$ is large. Then note that when $t$ is large, $\psi(t)$ is large, hence $G_1\circ \psi$ will be in those same quadrants. But this is not what $G_2(t)$ does when $t$ is large.